# Is g++ linker statically or dynamically linking libusb and pthreads?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, linker, g++

When adding `-lusb-1.0` and `-pthread` to compilation command, are they statically or dynamically linked?

```
g++ -pthread -o myprog obj1.o obj2.o -lusb-1.0
```

ldd gives the following output

```
libusb-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fc4662b7000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc465af7000)
```

`.so` is a shared object. I am confused. If it is dynamically loading, how are the symbols resolved? I thought `.so` can be loaded only with [dlopen](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and to obtain address of a symbol one would use [dlsym](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html)

Comment: Please provide some [mre] in your question, and explicitly define what do you mean by statically linked. If `ldd` mentions a library, it is a shared object (since any static library `libfoo.a` won't appear in output of `ldd`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When adding -lusb-1.0 and -pthread to compilation command, are they statically or dynamically linked?

By default, the shared libraries are linked on Linux. Unless you ask for static linking, the respective shared libraries
for `-pthread` and `-lusb-1.0` will be linked. You can tell the linker that you want static linking via `-static` option if you need).

> .so is a shared object. I am confused. If it is dynamically loading, how are the symbols resolved?

It's dynamically *linked* - not loaded at compile time. But there does some work done by the static linker ([ld](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html)) at compile time so that when the libraries are loaded at run time by the dynamic linker ([ld.so](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html)), it knows how to locate the symbols.

What happens at compile time is that the static linker creates "stub" addresses for the symbols in shared libraries in the PLT section ([Procedure Link Table](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/ELF/zSeries/lzsabi0_zSeries/x2251.html#PROCEDURELINKAGETABLE)). At program load time (or when the symbols are referenced), the dynamic linker/loader "fills" those addresses to the actual addresses This is done via the GOT ([Global Offset Table](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/ELF/zSeries/lzsabi0_zSeries/x2251.html#GLOBALOFFSETTABLE)). So the actual symbol resolution & loading is done at runtime but with some help from the static linker at compile time.

> I thought .so can be loaded only with dlopen and to obtain address of a symbol one would use dlsym.

That's not true. Shared libraries can be linked both at compile time as well as opened at runtime via [`dlopen`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html). It's *far more* common to link at compile time than opened via `dlopen`. Pretty much all system binaries are in fact dynamically linked on Linux; dynamic linking is the default on all modern Linux systems.

Check out Drepper's [how to write shared libraries](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) if you're interested in details.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the detailed answer. I'll definitely look at the paper in the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Shared objects can be linked at compile time and are loaded at program start or they can be dynamically loaded at runtime with dlopen.

*"When adding -lusb-1.0 and -pthread to compilation command, are they statically or dynamically linked?"* If the compiler finds dynamic libraries it links against them. Otherwise it links against the static libraries.

This

```
libusb-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fc4662b7000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc465af7000)
```

means the dynamic libraries are linked at compile time.

Comment: shared libraries are linked both at build time and at runtime.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I didn't say the opposite but I perhaps didn't make it very clear.

Answer (score 0):

> I am confused. If it is dynamically loading, how are the symbols resolved?

## Notice that Linux is [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source), so you can download  and study the source code

(of the [kernel](https://kernel.org/), of the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) C and C++ compiler and its C++ standard library, of the [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) linker, of [libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl-libc](http://musl.libc.org/), of [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), of [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), of [libusb](https://libusb.info/).....).

On Linux, libraries are preferably and by default (if available) shared libraries. So dynamic linking by `gcc` or `g++` is the implicit preference. If no shared libraries is found, a static library is linked.

Before that read the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools), a good [C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html), the [*Linker and loaders*](https://www.iecc.com/linker/) book, the [Program Library HowTo](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/), [Assembler HowTo](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/index.html), [C++ dlopen HowTo](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/index.html), [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), [ld.so(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html), [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/), some [textbook on *Operating Systems*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html), and the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) and Drepper's [*How to write shared libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper. See also the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project (a free software project I created which uses `dlopen` for C++ code).

Take the habit of enabling [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug information (to later use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger) and warnings when compiling, so [do](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -c src1.cc -o obj1.o` and notice that order of arguments to `g++` do matter. And `g++` is actually running other programs (`cc1plus`, `as`, `ld`). Pass `-v`  to `g++`  to find out which ones.

> I thought .so can be loaded only with dlopen

No, the dynamic linker [ld.so(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) is loading shared libraries and might be invoked by [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). Use [ldd(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html), [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Read also [*Teach Yourself Programming in Ten Years*](http://norvig.com/21-days.html) and see [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/)